# How to pipe postfix into Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, postfix, pipe, codeigniter

I currently have postfix piping into a PHP script to process the email via an alias.

```
catchall: |/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/scripts/incoming_mail.php
```

However, I wish to use the DB config etc supplied in my CI project, so I need to provide a route such as:

```
catchall: |/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/cli.php /incoming_mail
```

The desired outcome of this would be that I run the incoming_mail controller.

If I try the above the email is bounced with the following:

```
Action: failed
Status: 5.2.0
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; cannot append message to file /incoming_mail:
cannot create file exclusively: Permission denied
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `cli.php` doing?

Comment: cli.php just initiates Codeigniter and sets a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot append message to file /incoming_mail: cannot create file exclusively: Permission denied

Above error message is thrown by postfix because you tell it to append email content to `/incoming_mail` , instead passing argument  `/incoming_mail` to `cli.php`.

According to [man 5 aliases](http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html)

> **|command**
>
> > Mail  is piped into command. Commands that contain special char-
> >      acters, such as whitespace, should be  enclosed  between  double
> >      quotes. See local(8) for details of delivery to command.

Since you aren't wrap the command that contain whitespace, postfix interpreted `/incoming_mail` as filename

> **/file/name**
>
> > Mail is appended to /file/name.  See  local(8)  for  details  of
> >      delivery  to  file.   Delivery  is not limited to regular files.
> >      For  example,  to  dispose  of  unwanted  mail,  deflect  it  to
> >      /dev/null.

Solution: wrap your command in alias file with double quotes

```
catchall: "|/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/cli.php /incoming_mail"
```

PS: [Jommaar solution](https://serverfault.com/a/690306/218590) to use `transport_maps` and `pipe` can be used too :)

Comment: I ended up piping to a small script, which piped stdin to cli.php with the argument. But when I have got some time I will try this out!

Answer (score 3):

Hi here is how I made a parser:

`/etc/postfix/master.cf` (postfix)

```
bounce-pipe    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=BDFORXhqu user=deploy argv=/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/emailmanager/public/index.php
```

transport (postfix)

```
mailtoparse@example.com bounce-pipe:
```

index.php - get data that you would be handle

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

Comment: Hi Jomaar, this is similar to what I have at the moment, but I need to pass an argument into the script

Comment: Hi Jim, than add the param after the `argv=/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/emailmanager/public/index.php` like `argv=/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/emailmanager/public/index.php job parser`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too great with postfix. I am currently pointing lots of domains to the catchall alias in the /etc/postfix/virtual file. Would I have to make changes there too or would this act as an alias also?